# Django - Apply changes in HTML & Static files without restarting dev server

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am working in a dev environment using the built in Django web server. One of the inconvenience that I have is everytime I make changes in HTML or Static files it does not apply when I reload the browser until I kill the dev server and run again.

```
python manage.py runserver localhost:8000
```

Is there a way so Django will reflect the changes instantly? Thanks in advance

Comment: That's weird, they should be reflected in the page without restarting the server. Do you have additional process to compile static files?

Comment: Have you run `collectstatic` command?

Comment: This happens to me sometimes when I enable caching, such as [a cached template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader)? Try using a [dummy cache backend for development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#dummy-caching-for-development).

Comment: You can find same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42782337/django-development-server-doesnt-detect-changes-in-my-html-files

Answer (score 1):

Django reload the server only on changes on .py files. I read different ways to trigger reloading (such as installing [a third party app](https://github.com/tjwalch/django-livereload-server), tweaking caching depending on whether `DEBUG = True`, etc etc).

The **easiest** and **dumbest** way is to make an insignificant slight change in the view you're working on (say, adding a `#`, removing it) after you edited and saved your template. It is dumb but it works.